# Can't run java applications

Tags: java, jar, ubuntu-16.04

I have trouble when trying to open my jar files with the following command:

```
java -jar software.jar
```

They load until a certain point and then nothing happens.
I deinstalled default-jdk and OpenJDK with synaptic and re-installed it with apt-get, but nothing changed. I had a similar problem one month ago and solved it (apparently only temporarly) by deleting the package gcj-5-jre-lib (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) (Java runtime library for use with gcj (jar files))

The following outputs will help:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

javac -version
1.8.0_131
```

My variables $JAVA_HOME and $JRE_HOME were correctly added to my $PATH.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

EDIT

Here is an example of what I get when I try to start PhyDE.jar

```
java -jar PhyDE.jar
Welcome to PhyDE 0.9971!
Reading preferences.
Creating PhyDE-Application window
Checking for updates...
You are using the latest version of PhyDE
Done with checking for updates
```

When checking the core use with the command top I see that the process is active, but the user interface does not open as it usually does. I am located in the folder where the jar file is, and same happens with other jar files.

Comment: Are you in the directory where .jar is located?

Comment: What *exactly* happens when you try to run a jar?

Comment: "They load until a certain point and then nothing happens." How do you know that?

Comment: I edited my thread to answer your comments